# Azure deployment script keeps complaining "CurrentStorageAccount is not set"

Tags: powershell, deployment, azure

I want to do automated deployment with Bamboo (a Continuous Integration solution). I found in here(http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/continuous-delivery/#script) a piece of script to help. The main code snippet:

```
#configure powershell with Azure 1.7 modules
Import-Module Azure

#configure powershell with publishsettings for your subscription
$pubsettings = $subscriptionDataFile
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile $pubsettings
Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccount $storageAccountName -SubscriptionName $selectedsubscription
write-host $storageAccountName
write-host "$selectedsubscription"

#set remaining environment variables for Azure cmdlets
$subscription = Get-AzureSubscription $selectedsubscription
$subscriptionname = $subscription.subscriptionname
$subscriptionid = $subscription.subscriptionid
$slot = $environment

#main driver - publish & write progress to activity log
Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Azure Cloud Service deploy script started."
Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Preparing deployment of $deploymentLabel for $subscriptionname with Subscription ID $subscriptionid."


Publish

$deployment = Get-AzureDeployment -slot $slot -serviceName $servicename
$deploymentUrl = $deployment.Url

Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Created Cloud Service with URL $deploymentUrl."
Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Azure Cloud Service deploy script finished."
```

I just first tried running this script from cmd by executing `powershell E:\CI\OCZDeployment\publish_cloud_service.ps1 -environment Staging -serviceName "ocz" -storageAccountName "t2vsoft" -packageLocation OCZ.cspkg -cloudConfigLocation ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg -subscriptionDataFile E:\CI\OCZDeployment\SubscriptionDataFile.publishsettings -selectedsubscription "Development Subscription"`

, where the publishsettings file is downloaded from Azure.

But I kept getting the error message:

> New-AzureDeployment : CurrentStorageAccount is not set. Use Set-AzureSubscription subname -CurrentStorageAccount storageaccount to set it.

It has definitely been set in the snippet. I even tried copy & paste the Set-AzureSubscription line to inside New-AzureDeployment function. No luck.

Help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed. Don't know what was exactly the cause but i removed all registered azure subscriptions by executing:

```
PS> Get-AzureSubscription | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzureSubscription $_.SubscriptionName }
```

and re-imported the subscription by executing:

```
PS> Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile xxx.publishsettings
```

and it all worked! :)

There really were some similarly-named subscriptions in the subscription list. There might have been conflicts as such the azure scripts didn't know which one they really wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple subscriptions then you need to make sure the subscription that you want to use is set to the default. This can be done with the following:

```
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "{subscriptionName}" -Default
```

if you aren't sure what your subscription name is you can use the following to see all of your subscriptions:

```
Get-AzureSubscription
```